# send email(with Chinese content) by Python, but raise: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, email

I just want to send email by Python, but there is something wrong with my code.
I've searched many web sites and all the answers didn't fit the error well.

Here is my code:

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.header import Header

import traceback
import sys

def send_email(subject, receiver, html_message):   
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    html_message = "你好"
    subject = "测试"
    msg['Subject'] = Header(subject, 'utf-8')
    msg['From'] = "我是谁"
    msg['To'] = "XXXX@163.com"
    html = MIMEText(html_message.encode('utf-8'), 'plain', 'utf-8')
        # 一开始想用html格式的邮件，但是编码死活弄不对，试了试plain还是不行
    msg.attach(html)
    try:
        smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP()
        smtp_obj.connect(DefaultConfig.MAIL_HOST, 25)    # 25 为 SMTP 端口号
        smtp_obj.login(xxx, *****)
        smtp_obj.sendmail(xxxx, xxxxx, msg.as_string())
        smtp_obj.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback_obj = sys.exc_info()
        traceback.print_tb(exc_traceback_obj)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
File "E:\Coding\tools\backend\lextool\utils\send_email.py", line 39, in send_email
    smtp_obj.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
  File "D:\win10\ANACONDA\lib\smtplib.py", line 855, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
```

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest try encoding"utf-8-sig" if "utf-8" doesn't work